# "Object variable or With block variable not set" error while adding data into ArrayList

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA so I'm not pretty sure what I'm doing. Please be kind.

What I'm trying to implement is, user select the files from File Picker and put the selected files' path into ArrayList.
I created fileList as global variable then initialize it in Workbook_Open event.

I'm getting `Object variable or With block variable not set` error in adding String into the ArrayList.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fileList As Object

Sub Browse_Click()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim oFD As Variant
    Dim Filepathname As String

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv", 1
        .Title = "Choose CSV File"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show

        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems
            Filepathname = oFD
            fileList.Add (Filepathname) // <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ERROR HERE
        Next oFD

        Dim Str As Object
        For Each Str In fileList
            MsgBox Str
        Next Str
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set fileList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
I want to initialize the ArrayList only once. User may click Browse button several time and I need to keep all the files he choose in that ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

With these changes code worked for me:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fileList As Object

Sub Browse_Click()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim oFD As Variant
    Dim Filepathname As String

    Set fileList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 'Initialization moved here
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.*", 1
        .Title = "Choose CSV File"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show

        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems
            Filepathname = oFD
            fileList.Add (Filepathname)
        Next oFD

        Dim Str As Variant  ' Changed to variant
        For Each Str In fileList
            MsgBox CStr(Str)   ' Added conversion to string
        Next Str
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: But `CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")` will initialize the ArrayList right? User may click the Browse button several time and I need the record of all the file he choose in the ArrayList.

Comment: Of course you can change back to your option. Remember to save & open workbook after that - otherwise macro wont work.

Comment: I use `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` instead and problem solved. Thanks bro